# What's the common practice in constituting the WHERE clause based on the user input

Tags: sql, oracle, client-side, where-clause

If we take a database table, we can query all the rows or we can choose to apply a filter on it. The filter can vary depending on the user input. In cases when there are few options we can specify different queries for those few specific conditions. But if there are lots and lots of options that user might or might not specify, aforementioned method does not come handy. I know, I can compose the filter based upon the user input and send it as a string to the corresponding stored procedure as a parameter, build the query with that filter and finally execute the query string with the help of EXECUTE IMMEDIATE(In Oracle's case). Don't know why but I really don't like this way of query building. I think this way I leave the doors open for SQL injectors. And besides, that I always have trouble with the query itself as everything is just a string and I need to handle dates and numbers carefully.What is the best and most used method of forming the WHERE clause of a query against a database table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common way of approaching this problem is building *expression trees* that represent your query criteria, converting them to *parameterized* SQL (to avoid SQL injection risks), binding parameter values to the generated SQL, and executing the resultant query against your target database.

The exact approach depends on your client programming framework: .NET has *Entity Framework* and *LINQ2SQL* that both support expression trees; Java has Hibernate and JPA, and so on. I have seen several different frameworks used to construct customizable queries, with great deal of success. In situations when these frameworks are not available, you can roll your own, although it requires a lot more work.

Answer (score 2):

Using database parameters instead of attempting to quote your literals is the way forward.

This will guard you against SQL injection.

Comment: Using bind parameters does really protect against SQL Injections. But how do I build the filter if many many options can be specified. It' not guaranteed that all the filter options will be used. This means I have to check for the parameter value, if it's not null then add it to my WHERE clause, otherwise not. This gives the same result. Still I have to have something like IF MyPARAM1 IS NOT NULL THEN MYWHERE_CLAUSE:=MY_WHERECLAUSE||TO_CHAR(MYPARAM1).... And then MY_QUERY:=MY_QUERY||MY_WHERE_CLAUSE and so on. I want to avoid this.

Comment: If many many options are specified, then you'll need to include them.  Yep, it's onerous, but it's something we all have to do.